# SQL execution errors while deploying Sitecore 9.3 to Azure app service

Tags: azure, deployment

This is a follow-up question from another thread [Facing issue while deploying Sitecore 9.3 to Azure app service](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/36280/facing-issue-while-deploying-sitecore-9-3-to-azure-app-service).
Here are my scripts besides all parameter files

```
$SCSDK="F:\sitecore\azure\SAT250"
$SCTemplates="https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/tree/master/Sitecore%209.3.0/XPSingle/azuredeploy.json"
$DeploymentId = "sandstorm"
$LicenseFile = "C:\sc930_install\license.xml"
$SubscriptionId = "<subscriptionid>"
$Location="South Central US"
$ParamFile="F:\sitecore\azure\XPSingle\azuredeploy.parameters.json"
$ArmTemplatePath = "F:\sitecore\azure\XPSingle\azuredeploy.json"
$CertificateFile = "C:\certificates\star.demo789.pfx"

$Parameters = @{
     #set the size of all recommended instance sizes   
     #"sitecoreSKU"="Medium";
     "deploymentId"=$DeploymentId;
     "authCertificateBlob" = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($CertificateFile));
     #by default this installs azuresearch
     #if you uncomment the following it will use an existing solr connectionstring that
     # you have created instead of using AzureSearch
     #"solrConnectionString"= "https://myinstancesomewhere/solr";
}

Import-Module $SCSDK\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1 -Verbose

Connect-AzAccount -tenantid <tenantid>

Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

Start-SitecoreAzureDeployment -Verbose -Name $DeploymentId -Location $Location -ArmTemplateUrl $SCTemplates -ArmParametersPath $ParamFile  -LicenseXmlPath $LicenseFile  -SetKeyValue $Parameters
```

Unfortunately, I always got the following error:

```
ARM-MSDeploy Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedClientServerException: Could not deploy package.
Warning SQL72030: If this deployment is executed, changes to [xdb_collection].[ContactFacets] might introduce run-time errors in [xdb_collection].[GetContactFacetsChanges].
Warning SQL72030: If this deployment is executed, changes to [xdb_collection].[Contacts] might introduce run-time errors in [xdb_collection].[GetContactsChanges].
Warning SQL72030: If this deployment is executed, changes to [xdb_collection].[InteractionFacets] might introduce run-time errors in [xdb_collection].[GetInteractionFacetsChanges].
Warning SQL72030: If this deployment is executed, changes to [xdb_collection].[Interactions] might introduce run-time errors in [xdb_collection].[GetInteractionsChanges].
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 22115, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Change tracking is enabled for one or more tables in database 'sandstorm-shard0-db'. 
Disable change tracking on each table before disabling it for the database. Use the sys.change_tracking_tables catalog view to obtain a list of tables for which change tracking is enabled.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script:

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM   [sys].[databases] WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')    
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)] SET CHANGE_TRACKING = OFF WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;'
END
```

Any help is appreciated!

---

as suggested I deleted all previously leftover resources, re-run the scripts and no error.

Comment: Try deleting the existing `resource group` where an error occurred and run the fresh installation as an incomplete setup might create an issue while running a script on top of it. Clean up that `resource group` by deleting resources or delete the `resource group` itself and try again.

Comment: If clean-up does not help then try with a new `resource group`.

Comment: looks like sql databases still exist from previous install. Just delete those dbs and rerun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad that you are able to complete your setup. Make my comment as an answer to this question. As the below steps resolve your query mark this answer as accepted for community purposes.

To resolve the issue, please follow the below steps.

1. Try deleting the existing `resource group` where an error occurred and run the fresh installation as an incomplete setup might create an issue while running a script on top of it. `Clean up` that `resource group` by deleting `resources` or delete the resource group itself and try again.
2. If clean-up does not help then try with a new `resource group`.

Hope it helps!